# Ubuntu package installation - get % progress

Tags: software-installation

I'm wondering, if there is possible to get percentage progress of package installation?
Maybe if you read number of packages that has to be installed and then you have to calculate...but question now is, how to get number of packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On ubuntu 14.04:**

You can turn on the fancy progress bar in apt by running the following commands on a terminal (open by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing "terminal"):

```
sudo -i
```

and then enter your password and then

```
echo 'Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "1";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar
```

Note that this will give you the percentage for package installation and not downloading + installation. You already get the percentage of file(s) downloaded in apt without any configuration changes.

[(Source)](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-enable-apt-terminal-progress-bar)